# Denotational semantics of object-oriented languages

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented, denotational-semantics

I am interested in denotational semantics of object oriented languages. Namely, what are the common/typical denotations of objects used in the literature? Is this an interesting topic these days?

The most comprehensive article I've found dates back to [1993](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~udr/papers/oosem.pdf). That made me think that I might be missing something. Am I?

Comment: Depends on what  you mean by denotational semantics. If you are interested in classical order-theoretic denotational semantics, then there is probably not all that much, as it has proven difficult to do this convincingly for OO-languages. These days OO is considered mostly operationally or axiomatically.

Comment: @MartinBerger Yes, I am interested in mapping objects back to some semantic domain.

Comment: What's a semantic domain? Do you accept logical formulae as a semantic domain?

Comment: A (semantic) domain is just a complete partial order with a least element.

Comment: I doubt that you will find much then. It might be possible to turn logical formulae (ordered by implication) associated with axiomatic semantics into a suitable semantic domain. I have not seen it spelled out though.